# How to extract & display easily in Chrome a sessionId variable from HTTPS URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, google-chrome-devtools, session-variables

I currently authenticate (login/password) to a website in chrome with UI, and need the sessionId, which is not shown directly in the main URL in tab.

So I retrieve it manually in Developer Tools from background GET URLs.

Background URLs which are like : https://website.com/product/page?variable=0000&sessionId=ABCDEFGH.sometext

I need "ABCDEFGH".

Currently my path is :

- Connect in UI with login/pwd (which is fine)
- Opening Developer Tools → Network
- Filtering "&sessionId="
- Right-Clicking on a URL → Copy → Copy Link Address

I don't code in Chrome / Javascript / Developer Tools.

How could I create an easy "extension" or an alert box to display this URL, and so the sessionId automatically in 1 or 2 clicks.

Ideally :

- I'm logged in
- 1 or 2 clicks
- get automatically a URL or sessionId directly, without manually filtering in Dev Tools

Comment: Implementing this isn't exactly trivial, so your best bet is finding some extension that can display a notification for a request that matches your custom condition or regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks, any idea where I can start for those "extensions" ? No idea how to do that ! @woxxom

Comment: I don't know either. Try googling or asking chatgpt.